# Jenkins recursive build issue

Tags: jenkins

I have a master branch on stash/git. Jenkins script is such that it checks out a branch from master and then from another(remote FNT) server commits in master. Git sees this commit and sends a notification to jenkins to kick start another build. and hence I get recursive builds.
To solve this problem I added a Git hook in stash to avoid triggering the Jenkins build if the commit is done from that user but that hook is nor working.
Any ideas or thoughts how I can stop recursive builds ?

Answer (score 2):

If the commits that need to be ignored are from a known user, you could configure the Jenkins job to not trigger from commits of that user.